# LUA convert complex table to lowercase

Tags: lua

Using LUA how would I convert a table such as this to all lowercase?

```
return {{[ [[House]] ] = [[bob]],[ [[Roof]] ] = [[steve]],[ [[Door-Knob]] ] = [[Richard]],[ [[Rug-Duty]] ] = [[mark]],},
```

Comment: `[[House]] ] = [[bob]]` , is that even possible? I mean if `bob` is a variable name then it should be but you should give some details about your program, provide some more code.

Comment: This is just the raw data from the datafile I am using.  To give a more precise example it is a table with the format of {"House":"bob", "Roof":"steve",}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input table is of the following format (I've purposefully mixed upper and lower case characters in it):

```
test_tbl = {["HOUse"]="BOB", ["Roof"]="STEVE"}
```

you can write a function as follows:

```
function convert_table(tbl_test)
  local output_table = {}
  for i, v in pairs(tbl_test) do
        output_table [string.lower(i)] = string.lower(v)                      
   end   
return output_table 
end
```

and after calling it: `local returned_table= convert_table(test_tbl)` you can verify that all `keys` and `values` are in lowercase:

```
for i,v in pairs(returned_table) do
  print(i,v)
end
```

Comment: The OP's table is nested, it starts with `{{`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think you are confused due to OP's bad formatting. If you look at OP's comment under his post you will see the correct format.

Comment: Thanks for the help, lua is so much more difficult to work with tables than python.

Comment: @JoseGonzales  No problem. If you think my answer was helpful to you, you can always accept it as correct.